# Maven Spring project structure in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I have a Maven project in Eclipse which I am using to build a Spring MVC application. However, I am very confused about how the project structure should be. I've looked at various sources online and they often differ.

My current project structure (a bit of a mess..):

[image]

Which source folders do I need in Java Resources? Obviously `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` but what about `src/main/webapp`? What goes in there?

I see that there is a `src` directory generated when I build the project. What's the purpose of this directory?

Do I put my static resources e.g. 'style.css' in `WebContent/resources` or in a different directory?

Finally, how should my Deployment Assembly mappings look?

Update as per suggestion (not yet solved):

[image]

Comment: this is why spring boot was invented : learn it here https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/   or http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-boot-tutorials/

Comment: Maven does not provide well for having code and web files in the same project.

Comment: @georgesvan Thanks but I'd like to get my head around this project structure without having to learn a new technology

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Is that a sarcasm? petehallw: Just follow Maven standard.

Comment: @AleksandrM No. A statement. Split code and web pages in separate projects.

Answer (score 1):

src/main/webapp contains the css html and js related files. if you are aware of webContent folder the same things resides inside the webapp folder.You will need to remove the webcontent folder and place all the files in src/main/webapp folder.

Comment: Hi, I have taken your suggestion and provided a screenshot. How do I now set up my Deployment Assembly etc? I am getting a 404... Do I really not need the WebContent directory?

Comment: Yes according to maven structure you do not need the WebContent Directory. Check your web.xml and spring configuration files. It should do or post the same files here.